# Change Spyder's error colors

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I would like to change the Error colors in the IPython console in Spyder. Is that possible? I use Spyder 3.6 (if it matters). The error message is a mix of green and yellow... I have no know issues with my vision and I find it quite hard to read.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Colors were not set correctly after kernel restarts, but that was fixed in our 3.2.7 version. Please update to that version to see if that fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Update? I have the 3.6 version. Downgrade?

Comment: That's your Python version, not your Spyder version. If you're using Anaconda, simply run in a terminal (cmd.exe) `conda update spyder`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4891), the colors in iPython console are hardcoded and cannot be changed by Spyder itself.

One suggestion would be to switch to a dark background, so that colors like yellow are much easier to read. To do that, you can go to: Tools -> Preferences -> IPython console -> Display and click on Dark background.

Another alternative could be to use IPython %color magic to modify color scheme: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/details.html#terminal-colors

Comment: I can't find the "Dark background" under IPython console -> Display.
Edit: I found Spyder Dark under syntax coloring and that looks a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/916), it seems as if the colour scheme cannot be changed at this moment in time.

Hopefully, the feature will be supported in future. You could try looking into a different IDE that might suit your needs.